# Unable to login to GitHub after Disabling TLS

Tags: github, tls1.2, github-enterprise

We are in the process of setting up GitHub enterprise behind our load balancer and firewall.We would like to offload SSL on the load balancer for this purpose. But when we disabled the TLS on the GitHub admin page we are not able to login to GitHub.

Can we get this enabled through the SSH console ?

Answer (score 0):

We got it working after disabling the TLS option in the privacy section of the admin page. The ports to access the services gets changed after the appliance restarts

Comment: What did you do to get logged back in?